# XAML Designer caching files from debug directory to AppData

Tags: visual-studio, xaml-designer

My Visual Studio 2022, latest build is caching files from my debug directory to
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_7336a8d5\Designer

My system started getting slow when using VS, after looking into ResMon and Taskmanager, my SSD was at 100% and was writing my whole picture database settings folder to cache.

[Resmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fQO2.png)

It starts caching when the xaml designer opens up.

It happens even if it's a blank usercontrol xaml.

I had this problem for maybe two VS builds back.

I coudn't find any info on this, asked AI and looked through settings.